# Existing English word database with word forms?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request

Where can I find a database of English words that has the various forms for each word? Specifically, it would give the plural and singular form with its indefinite article for each noun, the various forms, tenses, and voices for verbs, and the comparative and superlative for adjectives. It would be easy to use it to solve queries like (noun,plural,"fish") and (verb,past,"to go").

Comment: There is Wiktionary but it is only semi-structured and doesn't have an API at the level you need. In its early days some of us tried to include whether each noun should be preceded by *a* or *an*, but that didn't catch on.

Comment: Pattern.en is not a database, but it does very well at this, and other related tasks  (http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en). English is rules-y enough that you can do it programmatically with a finite exception list. Unfortunately the designers of pattern.en only have a citation for the part of that code which does pluralization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here, maybe there's something useful among those tools: http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English

Technical note:
A "database" would be a less than ideal format for a language's morphology given the high redundancy among different word forms (all with the same stem); one typically uses a finite state machine/transducer for that.